# Passing environment variable to PHP via vagrant provisioning

Tags: php, wordpress, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm desperately trying to pass an environment variable to PHP via a vagrant provision, I'm using VCCW(http://vccw.cc/), I tried manually adding it to my vagrant/.profile file but I couldn't access it in PHP via getenv(), which is my goal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you add to the profile ? I suspect you add that on your root account but not your vagrant account

Comment: @FrédéricHenri don't remember exactly which command I wrote, but I clearly see in my /home/vagrant/.profile the key=>value I added, with the export command:
`export POTATO='YES'`
I run `whoami`and I get `vagrant`, I check which user owns the apache process and I also get `vagrant`

Comment: its weird .. so if you login to the vm, run `echo $POTATO` you see the value ? then a dummy php script with `<?php echo getenv("POTATO"), ?>` does not read the value ?

Comment: After ssh'ing into the VM I don't see the value when running `echo $POTATO`, I do have a dummy PHP script with exactly that and it does not echo the value either.

Comment: and you say its your `.profile` file ? if you run `source .profile` can you run `echo $POTATO` ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Yes, that works.

Comment: ok so it might be a bash issue - which box are you using ? meantime you can add the variable in `.bash_profile` rather than `.profile`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri the box is called `vccw-team/xenial64`
Added to `.bash_profile` but still not accessible from PHP with `getenv()`